# left integration of functor in the category of groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, derived-functors

Assume that a  functor on the category of groups vanishes on all projective objects. Is it necessarily the left derived functor of a half exact functor on this category?

Comment: Is this true for functors out of abelian categories? I wasn't aware.

Comment: do you mean an endofunctor? or you mean "to itself"? In any case, are there derived functors in such a non-additive setting?

Comment: What is the model structure on the category of groups? Or is it just abelian groups??

Comment: @MarkGrant  I was not aware of this in abelian category. Is the proof  obvious  in this case?

Comment: @YCor  what is the  difference between endofunctor and a functor from a category to itself? You are right. I was mistaken touse the terminilogy for  non abelian category. But what are obstructions to have the derived functors in non abelian categories? In what step of construction of derived functor we need "abelian"-ness?

Comment: @BugsBunny  I would appreciate if you read my previous two comments.

Comment: @AliTaghavi: My comment was really about the motivation for the question. If you don't know this to be true in abelian categories, why would you suspect it to be true in the (non-abelian) category of groups?

Comment: By the way, there exists a subject of non-abelian homological algebra (see work of Barr-Beck, Inassaridze and others). The projective objects in the category of groups are precisely the free groups.

Comment: @MarkGrant  thank you very much for your very helpful comment

Comment: "I would appreciate if you read my previous two comments." I did and see what happened. I still have not understood your question --  the right strategy is to give an answer then :-))

Comment: @MarkGrant  I did not see your two previous comment. the reason I considered the category of non abelian group is thst I was initially interested in commutator functor and wss curiious if it is derived functor. so i considered non abelian category. Any way what is the answer for abelian group?

Comment: @AliTaghavi: I see. I'm not sure what you mean by the commutator functor. If you mean the abelianisation, or the derived (commutator) subgroup, then neither of these vanish on free groups. I don't know the answer to your question for abelian groups, that's why I asked if you did.

Comment: @MarkGrant I meant $G\mapsto G'=[G,G]$ yes it does not vanish on free group. Now I see why did you pointed out to abelian group.  thanks again for your attention to my question.

Comment: @MarkGrant so I realize that maybe the abelian case is not known

Comment: If you want an answer to this question, could you clarify what you mean by "left derived functor" and "half-exact functor" for a category that is not additive? There might be versions of these concepts that work for more general categories, but I think the person asking the question should make it clear what versions they have in mind, to reduce confusion for readers.

Comment: @MarkGrant Is it clear that "left derived functors" and "half-exact functors" still work in this setting? BTW I think this is more like Bourne et al ("protomodular" etc etc) than Barr-Beck but I am very rusty so I may be confused.